# Change y axis values and scale

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am using RStudio.
I´m trying to change the values of the x-axis to 20 - 35 and with an interval of 0,625. However, I don´t seem to find the right code. if  I use this code:

```
ggplot(a1diurnalInflow, aes(x=Time, y=Potential.Air.Temperature....C.,group=1)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_line() +
    coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 35))
```

The output is weird (see picture two)

Picture one is the plot how it is right now with this code

```
ggplot(a1diurnalInflow, aes(x=Time, y=Potential.Air.Temperature....C.,group=1)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()
```

Kind regards,
Giorgia

[♦Current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VF7yA.png)
[Wrong output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GOOk.png)

Comment: please check this :https://stackoverflow.com/a/73250754/5224236

Comment: It looks like Potential.Air.Temperature is a character or factor variable rather than a number. Try doing `a1diurnallnflow$Potential.Air.Temperature....C <- as.numeric(as.character(a1diurnallnflow$Potential.Air.Temperature....C))` and re-running your code.

Comment: thanks for the reply!! However when I try to run this code, NA´s are introduced into the Air Temperature column

Comment: Can you provide the data from `a1diurnalInflow` using `dput()`? This will make your code reproducible for others.